# Integrating CRM platform to Google Home

Tags: database, crm, actions-on-google, google-home

Can you integrate a CRM platform database (i.e Salesforce) to create customized responses from Google Home?

Answer (score 1):

Probably on some way, at least for Google Home where the variables and speech bias  can be dynamic. The question is more what should the result be? 
And is it good? 
Is it usable?

Alexa has already an Salesforce Skill but I dont know it. So no idea if its useful.